# No custom functions option in FileMaker 18

Tags: filemaker

I have just started with FileMaker Pro and have been following some fundamental tutorials. I would like to start using Custom Functions in FileMaker. However, I cannot see the Custom Function menu option. I am using a trial version of FileMaker Pro Advanced 18 and cannot find a Custom Function option anywhere in the menus.

I've tried it with different installations on PC and Mac but have the same problem. I'd be very grateful for any FM experts who might be able to tell me what the problem is here.

An example of the custom function option I have been trying to access can be found in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBXco8D2uhc).

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the Advanced tools in the Preferences.

Comment: thanks! None of the tutorials I have seen actually mention that essential step.

Comment: @mikeym Always consult the online help first: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help%2Fusing-custom-functions.html

Comment: @mikeym The tutorials you're following might be a few years old and this change is quite recent. Until version 17 there were separate versions for Pro and Advanced, and you needed the advanced version to create and edit custom functions among other things. From 17 onward they discontinued FileMaker Pro and instead included the advanced tools for everyone as an option in the preferences.